# Javascript Unit Test addEventListener Syntax

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, addeventlistener

What's the correct syntax for the Unit Test?

The following works when I open it in a browser. The intent is to read the contents of the input box `ib` whenever it is changed, and to write an interpreted value of it into the table cell `c5` ...

```
var c5 = document.createElement('td');

var ib = document.createElement('input');
// For all browsers except IE before Version 9 -see http://help.dottoro.com/ljeuqqoq.php
if (ib.addEventListener)
    {
    ib.addEventListener('change', Action01InputBox (ib, c5), false);
    }
// For IE before Version 9 -see http://help.dottoro.com/ljeuqqoq.php
    else {
        if (ib.attachEvent){
        ib.addEventListener('change', Action01InputBox (ib, c5), false);
        }
    }
```

Here's the event listener. Of course, it returns a function.

NB the function `EmptyNode(c5)` simply deletes all the contents of the target node and `RealNumberFromInput (ib.value)` gets a real number from the input string via a regex...

```
function Action01InputBox (ib, c5)
{
    return function ()
    {
        EmptyNode(c5);
        var r = RealNumberFromInput (ib.value);
        c5.appendChild(document.createTextNode(r));
    };
};
```

Here's the unit test ...

```
Action01InputBoxTest = TestCase("Action01InputBoxTest");

Action01InputBoxTest.prototype.test01 = function()
{   
    // Text box
    var r = 0.123;
    var ib = document.createElement('input');
    ib.setAttribute('value', document.createTextNode(r));

    // Target cell
    var c5 = document.createElement('td');
    c5.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Bogus"));

    // Do action
    Action01InputBox(ib, c5);
    assertEquals(c5.textContent, r);    
};
```

The `textContent` of `c5` should have changed from "Bogus" to "0.123", so the test fails.

If I understand it rightly, the problem is that the test calls the return value of the event listener, rather than the function, but I can't work out how call the function properly from the test.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`ActionInputBox` should be a wrapped in an anonymous function:

```
ib.addEventListener('change', function(){Action01InputBox (ib, c5)}, false);
```